# Joining tables directly from foreign key to foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

I have a simple question, if I have three tables A, B, and C as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
`id` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `B` (
`emp_id` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`phone` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `A`(`id`));

CREATE TABLE `C` (
`emp_id` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`desk_no` INT(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `A`(`id`)
```

Is it good practice to take a join directly on C.emp_id = B.emp_id or should I join (A.id = B.emp_id) as R and then do join R.id = C.emp_id?  I ask because it makes sense that you could join B and C directly but is that dangerous because this joins a foreign key to another foreign key rather than a foreign key to a primary key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are free to do the join, even encouraged if it is the right thing to do.

But, with caution.  Such a join can result in a cartesian product for each employee.  So, an employee that has 3 phones and 4 desks would result in 12 records -- every combination of the phones and desks for that employee.  Furthermore, employees who are missing a record on one side or the other would lose records in an inner join.

Note that joining back to the original table does *not* fix this problem, which arises because you are joining along different dimensions of the data.  You just need to realize that this might occur.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the end result you are expecting. If you need any columns from Table A then you might need to join Table A, else your Foreign Key relation and NOT NULL conditions would take care, you need not join Table A

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys in SQL are used to check and enforce referential integrity, not to join tables.

There is no rule like JOIN should have primary key or foreign key. Keys provide integrity and performance. You can join tables even they do not keys at all. Foreign keys and Join serve different purposes.